# activate radio buttons on mouse down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, mouseevent

I am building an interface for a touchscreen and need the radio buttons to be activated on mouse down since I do not know if the touchscreen being used will listen for other events.  Is there anyway to replace the native functionality of an html form to mouse down?

Thanks

Comment: Look up `touchstart`. This has been answered many many times before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a mousedown event listener to the forms.

you can use jquery.

```
//on jquery ready
$(function(){
    $('form input').mousedown(function(e){
        $(e.currentTarget).click();
    })
})
```

Here is a fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/PgD5L/

Answer (score 0):

As stated by pattmorter, you can use the touchstart Event in your html. You can use this to trigger a function.

```
<input type='radio' touchstart='yourfunction()' value='Radio Title'></input>
```

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchstart